# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.16.1 in aws nodejs project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a Nodejs project, when testing it locally it works without any problem, but at the time of deployment it shows me the error **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.16.1**, 
realizing a debug I realized that error is when trying to connect to a SqlServer database that is in the main path of the project.

This is the code:

```
router.get('/',async (req, res, next) => {
  await dbConnection.query("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[WMS_Movimientos]", (err, result) => {
    console.log(result.recordsets[0].length)
    console.log(result)
    res.render('layouts/main', {
      movTable : result
    });
  });
});
```

I think it may be a timeout problem, but I still haven't got it to work

Comment: Console log the error and post here.

Comment: This is the error code: 'ETIMEOUT',

Comment: The database that is also in aws does not want to return response, do not know if it requires any permission?

Comment: Check your database firewall... Is it RDS or hosted inside ec2?